# How does one get the most recent call for a mock function in jest?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

If I have a mock function say `myMockFunction` I know I can check its calls like so:

```
const firstCall = myMockFunction.mock.calls[0];
```

Is there an easy/clean way to get the most recent call?

I think that the following would work:

```
const mostRecentCall = myMockFunction.mock.calls[myMockFunction.mock.calls.length -1];
```

This seems rather hacky/tiresome, is there a cleaner/easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [jest v27.5.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v27.5.0) on there is a new property `lastCall`:

```
const mostRecentCall = myMockFunction.mock.lastCall;
```

Answer (score 16):

If calls is an array and you don't care to preserve its contents, you could do `myMockFunction.mock.calls.pop()` to get the last call.

Comment: I dig it. If a better answer doesn't come up I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: This is a bad answer as it performs side effect on calls itself

Comment: You don't want to mutate the `calls` array, so I wouldn't do this

Comment: Mutating state isn't inherently evil, that's just FP dogma, you just need to be mindful of what you are doing. State should not be shared between tests so your mocks will only be scoped to your test function, which itself should be small and destroyed as soon as it has run, so there is no side effect outside the test.

It's perfectly valid to mutate the state of a mock if you only need to do it once, say to extract the last value to a variable with a meaningful name. As long as you never touch it again it doesn't matter, and the risk of that happening in a well written test is negligible.

Answer (score 10):

https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#custom-matchers

`expect(myMockFunction).lastCalledWith()`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to access the last element by slicing backwards:

```js
myMockFunction.mock.calls.slice(-1)[0]
```

Of course, if you don't have any calls yet, you'll get an `undefined`. Depending on your tests, that may or may not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the jest documentation,
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

```js
// The last call to the mock function was called with the specified args
expect(mockFunc.mock.calls[mockFunc.mock.calls.length - 1]).toEqual([
  arg1,
  arg2,
]);
```

Usage of pop alters the the mock.calls array